# custom seek bar for a streaming video file in android

Tags: android, video, streaming

How can we display a custom seek bar for a streaming video file in android?

Comment: how are you streaming the video, and what's the format, and what's the player?  Is it the normal MediaPlayer java class, for example?

Answer (score 10):

Hi you can use below code to implemen custom seekbar for your video view,

```
 videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                seekBar.setMax(videoView.getDuration());
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }
        });

    private Runnable onEverySecond=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(seekBar != null) {
                seekBar.setProgress(videoView.getCurrentPosition());
            }

            if(videoView.isPlaying()) {
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }

        }
    };

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            if(fromUser) {
                // this is when actually seekbar has been seeked to a new position
                videoView.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) class. You can then use `setProgress()` and `setSecondaryProgress()`.

If you want to change the style, see this question: [How to customize the look of a SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187154/how-to-customize-the-look-of-a-seekbar-in-android)