# How to customize the look of a SeekBar in Android?

Tags: android, seekbar

I use a `SeekBar` in my application and I would like to customize it a little bit. I already figured out how to change the `Drawable` for the thumb and for the background.

My question is how to change the size of the `SeekBar`? If I just change the height of the `SeekBar like this, the`View`is only clipped and it only shows the top piece of the`SeekBar`:

```
<SeekBar
   android:layout_height="10dip"
   style="@style/seekbar_style" />
```

How do I change the overall size of the `Seekbar`? I want it to be much thinner then the standard `SeekBar`.

Comment: you can go through this tutorial as well.
http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure about Seekbars, but Progressbars can be customized by using a custom style (defined in your styles.xml) like so:

```
<style name="MyCustomProgressStyle">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">10dip</item>
</style>
```

Then you can set up a custom drawable based on the android system's `progress_horizontal.xml` (it's in the `frameworks/base/core/res/drawable` folder of an [AOSP checkout](http://source.android.com/source/download.html)). Here's [an example](http://code.google.com/p/android-target/source/browse/trunk/res/drawable/progress_horizontal.xml?r=13) from an open-source project.

Answer (score 23):

You have the equivalent of this of the Progress Bar for the seekbar indeed :

```
  <style name="Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@android:drawable/seek_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">8px</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
  </style>
```

So you might want to override all this and do it your way, as you would do it for the title bar, by defining your own style.

Comment: this works for me & shows how to change the "thumb" image (I just can't figure out what the "thumbOffset" is for)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier thumbOffset is just an invisible 'gap' between the thumb and the edges of the seekbar itself. You set it to stop the thumb from moving too far off the sides.

Comment: how to change the "thumb" image

Comment: @mohitum007 thumb image is changed by he following item:

<item name="android:thumb">@android:drawable/seek_thumb</item>